# How to save streaming audio using StreamingKit?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation

Currently I am using the [StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit) to play streaming mp3 files. I want to save 15 sec of the audio and convert that audio file to video file to share on Instagram.

I believe I have to implement

`[audioPlayer appendFrameFilterWithName:@"MyCustomFilter" block:^(UInt32 channelsPerFrame, UInt32 bytesPerFrame, UInt32 frameCount, void* frames)
{
   ...
}];`

to save the audio as mentioned here .https://stackoverflow.com/a/34326868/4110214

But do not know how to do it.

Could someone please guide me to  achieve this ?

Comment: did you find a solution to this please?

Comment: no I was not able to file a proper solution and we have excluded that feature from the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tab to save the PCM audio into files.

```
[audioPlayer appendFrameFilterWithName:@"MyCustomFilter" block:^(UInt32 channelsPerFrame, UInt32 bytesPerFrame, UInt32 frameCount, void* frames)
{
   ...
}];
```